# How to run CakePHP in a sub directory appear as the root

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to keep my root directory clean by not dumping the cake folders in the directory, but I don't want the url to be www.example.com/cake.  Instead I need it to be www.example.com

What's the best way to accomplish this?  I've been messing around with the htaccess files for a while, but have not yet resolved the issue.  So far I have figured out how to redirect to the subdirectory, but it shows up as www.example.com/cake, when I would like it to just show up as www.example.com.

I'm currently hosted on Media Temple GS, so I dont have access to the apache config files.

Thanks!

Comment: Cake's Bakery has a post how someone tackled similar to this: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/gedm/2009/08/29/installing-cakephp-on-shared-hosting

Comment: wcolbert: can you please answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065143/cakephp-2-5-4-redirection-url-after-form-submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place this into your root directory's `.htaccess` file

```
// .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$ cake/app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) cake/app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ish1301: 
Can you please reply to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065143/cakephp-2-5-4-redirection-url-after-form-submit

Answer (score 1):

There is routes.php file in app/config folder open it and it will look like

```
<?php

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'login'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

you just need to change the word login to any view file you want to load first when you open your site and its done................