# Cakephp 2.5.4: Redirection url after form submit

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I want to submit the form to **www.example.com/users/signup** but my page is submitting to **www.example.com/test/users/signup**.
Cakephp is installed in test folder. I have created htaccess inside test folder.
This is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$ test/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) test/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule    ^$ /test/users/signup  [L]
 RewriteRule users/signup /users/signup [L]
</IfModule>
```

**View:**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('url'=>array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'signup')), array('id' => 'signup',  'role' => 'form','class'=>'form-signin')); 

echo $this->Form->input('User.email',array('type'=>'email','required'=>'required','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Email'));

echo $this->Form->input('User.password',array('type'=>'password','required'=>'required','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Password'));
?>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign up</button>
<?php echo $this -> Form -> end(); ?>
```

I created the routes:

```
<?php

Router::connect('/users/signup', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'signup'));
?>
```

**If you want to ask any query please feel free to ask.**

Comment: did you change the constants in your webroot index so your app knows it's located inside the '/test/' folder?

Comment: @Dave No I did not change

Comment: You probably need to.

Comment: Okay, what I have to change there, please tell me @Dave

Comment: These are the constants defined, which constant I need to update?
These are set by default:
WEBROOT_DIR="webroot"
WWW_ROOT="/home/example/public_html/test/app/webroot/"
CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH= "/home/example/public_html/test/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php"

Comment: Thanks, i founded my answer @Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/signup is the route I connected in routes.php - it's a "pretty url" so I don't have the default /{controller}/{action} format. If the site is not in a sub-folder, any form I generate with $this->Form->create() POSTs to /signup. However, when in the sub-folder, I can see the page at /signup but all generated URLs include the sub-folder. I want the site to work as though there is no sub-folder and behave as though it's in the root. Setting Configure::write('App.baseUrl, '/'); did the trick.

Solution is: Configure::write('App.baseUrl, '/');